# Metropolis algorithm to Bernoulli likelihood and beta prior (Kruschke 7.3.1)

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, metropolis-hastings

This question pertains to a specific line written in the book *[Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/)* by John K. Kruschke.

In section 7.3.1, he applies Metropolis algorithm to a case with: $prior =  beta(\theta|1,1), N = 20,$ and $z = 14$. Then he proposes jumps with $normal(0, \sigma)$ where $\sigma$ can be 0.02, 0.2 or 2.

When $\sigma = 0.2$ he writes that jump is between +-0.2 for 68% of the time(which I understand) and proposed jumps are accepted roughly half the time as $N_{acc}/N_{pro} = 0.495$. I do not understand this - how do I get to this result.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an empirical result?

Comment: @jbowman, I am not sure, he just says, author has not written whether it is empirical or mathematical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not provide the likelihood, let us assume that $Z|\theta$ is a Binomial $\mathcal{B}(20,\theta)$ variate and its realisation is $z=14$. The posterior distribution on $\theta$ is then a Beta $\mathcal{B}e(15,7)$ [for which MCMC is not required].

If running a Normal random walk proposal for simulating this target, the moves are accepted with probability
$$\min\left\{ \dfrac{\pi(\theta')}{\pi(\theta_t)},1\right\}$$
where $\pi(\cdot)$ is the density of the Beta $\mathcal{B}e(15,7)$. This means running a code like

```
T=1e4
p=rep(runif(1),T)
for (t in 2:T){
  p[t]=prop=p[t-1]+rnorm(1,sd=.2)
  if ((prop<0)|(prop>1)|(runif(1)>dbeta(prop,15,7)/dbeta(p[t-1],15,7)))
    p[t]=p[t-1]}
length(unique(p))/T
```

which returns 0.4862 in my case

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as mentioned in the title it is "Bernoulli Likelihood". I do understand the empirical result, waiting if someone can prove theoretically.